# Regex in Google Analytics Advanced Custom Filter not working as expected

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm trying to setup a custom advanced filter in Google analytics to remove a particular query parameter (`sys_id`) from the URL when another parameter (`id=ticket`) is set in the URL.

For example, I want this URL:

```
/sp?id=ticket&table=incident&sys_id=cb7a9061db05c300d70a38ff9d9619f8
```

to be captured as:

```
/sp?id=ticket&table=incident
```

In my custom advanced filter, I have **Field A -> Extract A** set to *Request URI* with regex: `(.*id\=ticket.*)(&sys_id=(\w|\d){32})($|\&.*)`

In the **Output To -> Constructor**, I have set *Request URI* to `$A1$A3`

Result: Google analytics is logging `/sp?id=ticket&table=incident8`

Why am I getting the last character (the `8` in the above example) at the end of the string and how do I get rid of it to get just the output I want?

Comment: Try replacing `(\w|\d){32}` with `\w{32}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did it! Please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third capturing group `(\w|\d){32}` in your pattern is a repeated capturing group, and it stores the last captured value in the group memory buffer (the `8` in your test case).

Since `\w` already matches digits, you do not even need the alternation group. You may safely replace `(\w|\d){32}` with `\w{32}`.